# What is the correct way to pass data to table cells with click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to come up with a way to implement a click listener to each cell at a table. I realized that selector `'td:eq(index)'` is letting me put an event listener individually to each cell.

However, I realized that each time this piece of code runs, all the cells get the last value of the variables. Meaning all the values are updated each time the code runs and I can't assign varying data to each cell.

How do I fix this ? Where am I going wrong? What is the correct way to actually accomplish this ?  Here is what I am talking about:

```
var k = 0; var x = 1; var y = 1;
$('#output').on('click','td:eq('+k +')',function(){
    $(this).text((x).toString()+'.'+(y).toString())
})
```

This puts the click listener and the element turns to `1.1` after click.
However when I run the code a second time:

```
k = 1; x = 2; y= 2;
$('#output').on('click','td:eq('+k +')',function(){
    $(this).text((x).toString()+'.'+(y).toString())
})
```

I get two click listeners placed in the right spot, but both values are `2.2`

I case anyone wonders, `output` is my table div and this is how I create the table:

```
$('#output').append('<table border = \"1\">');

for(var i = 0; i< intHeight;i++){

    $('#output').find('table').append('<tr> id=' + i+"."+j);
    for(var j = 0; j < intWidth; j ++){
            intCell = 'click me';
            var current = $(this); 

             $('#output').find('tr:last').append('<td>'+intCell)

    }
}
```

Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Without your HTML, and any specific instruction as to precisely which cell(s) you need, it may be difficult to answer your question. But you say, in the text of the question, you want to bind a click event-handler to *all* table cells? So why not: `$('table').on('click', 'td', function(){...});`? There doesn't seem to be a need for the `:nth-child selector()` or an explicit loop. Depending upon the content of the table, though, you could simply omit the `'td'` selector, and just bind directly to the table itself: `$('table').on('click', function(){ ... });`

Comment: @DavidThomas. My problem is assigning that data. What I was thinking that by doing `td:eq(index)` only the indexed `<td></td>` would have the value that was  assigned in the function. So doing what you suggested only fills each cell with the last value of `x` and `y`. What I want is to be able to assign different values.

Comment: Then we need more information; "*[m]y problem is assigning that data*" - what data? "*...only the indexed `<td></td>` would have the value that was assigned in the function.*" - what function? What exactly are you trying to achieve? How does the user interact with your page, what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to **pass data to table cells with click listener**.

```js
data = Array($('td').length).fill().map((v, i) => i);

$('td').each(function(index) {
    $(this).data('number', data[index])
    $(this).click(function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify($(this).data()))
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click on Cell to Reveal Data</h3>
<table style="width: 100%;" border="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- DivTable.com -->
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/s7mzt3uw/1/)